# Accessing struct members directly

Tags: c++, memory, struct

I have a testing struct definition as follows:

```
struct test{
    int a, b, c;
    bool d, e;
    int f;
    long g, h;
};
```

And somewhere I use it this way:

```
test* t = new test;   // create the testing struct
int* ptr = (int*) t;
ptr[2] = 15;          // directly manipulate the third word
cout << t->c;         // look if it really affected the third integer
```

This works correctly on my Windows - it prints 15 as expected, but is it safe? Can I be really sure the variable is on the spot in memory I want it to be - expecially in case of such combined structs (for example f is on my compiler the fifth word, but it is a sixth variable)?

If not, is there any other way to manipulate struct members directly without actually having struct->member construct in the code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you are asking two questions

**Is it safe to treat &test as a 3 length int arrray?**

It's probably best to avoid this.  This may be a defined action in the C++ standard but even if it is, it's unlikely that everyone you work with will understand what you are doing here.  I believe this is not supported if you read the standard because of the potential to pad structs but I am not sure.

**Is there a better way to access a member without it's name?**

Yes.  Try using the [offsetof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstddef/offsetof.html) macro/operator.  This will provide the memory offset of a particular member within a structure and will allow you to correctly position a point to that member.

```
size_t offset = offsetof(mystruct,c);
int* pointerToC = (int*)((char*)&someTest + offset);
```

Another way though would be to just take the address of c directly

```
int* pointerToC = &(someTest->c);
```

Comment: Thanks a million. Did not know `offsetof`! Been calling myself a C++ programmer for the last 6 years.

Answer (score 5):

No you can't be sure. The compiler is free to introduce padding between structure members.

Answer (score 4):

To add to [JaredPar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623693/accessing-struct-members-directly/623709#623709), another option in C++ only (not in plain C) is to create a pointer-to-member object:

```
struct test
{
  int a, b, c;
  bool d, e;
  int f;
  long g, h;
};

int main(void)
{
  test t1, t2;

  int test::*p;  // declare p as pointing to an int member of test
  p = &test::c;  // p now points to 'c', but it's not associating with an object
  t1->*p = 3;    // sets t1.c to 3
  t2->*p = 4;    // sets t2.c to 4

  p = &test::f;
  t1->*p = 5;    // sets t1.f to 5
  t2->*p = 6;    // sets t2.f to 6
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for the `offsetof` macro. This will get you the byte offset of the member. You can then manipulate the member at that offset. Note though, this macro is implementation specific. Include `stddef.h` to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not safe and is 100% un-readable; thus making that kind of code unacceptable in real life production code.

Answer (score 0):

use set methods and boost::bind for create functor which will change this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from padding/alignment issues other answers have brought up, your code violates strict aliasing rules, which means it may break for optimized builds (not sure how MSVC does this, but GCC `-O3` will break on this type of behavior).  Essentially, because `test *t` and `int *ptr` are of different types, the compiler may assume they point to different parts of memory, and it may reorder operations.

Consider this minor modification:

```
test* t = new test;
int* ptr = (int*) t;

t->c = 13;
ptr[2] = 15;
cout << t->c;
```

The output at the end could be either `13` or `15`, depending on the order of operations the compiler uses.

Comment: No - as the valid statement `int* ptr = &(t->c);` shows, an int* may alias a test* if struct test contains (directly or indirectly) at least one int.

Comment: @MSalters - that doesn't make sense.  &(t->c) has type int*, which is not the same as using aliasing to "peek" into a structure.  For example, what if (char*)&(t->c) - (char*)t isn't a multiple of sizeof(int)?

Answer (score 0):

According to paragraph 9.2.17 of the standard, it is in fact legal to cast a pointer-to-struct to a pointer to its first member, providing the struct is [POD](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/intrinsic-types.html#faq-26.7):

> A pointer to a POD-struct object,
>   suitably converted using a
>   reinterpret_cast, points to its
>   initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which
>   it resides) and vice versa. [Note:
>   There might therefore be unnamed
>   padding within a POD-struct object,
>   but not at its beginning, as necessary
>   to achieve appropriate alignment. ]

However, the standard makes no guarantees about the layout of structs -- even POD structs -- other than that the address of a later member will be greater than the address of an earlier member, provided there are no access specifiers (`private:`, `protected:` or `public:`) between them.  So, treating the initial part of your `struct test` as an array of 3 integers is technically undefined behaviour.